# Android SDK Manager is not showing ARM EABI v7a System Image option

Tags: android

I am trying to setup environment to build application on Android platform. 
I have followed steps from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html and did install SDK and Eclispe ADT Plugins. 
While running Hello World application, I received an error :

SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.

To overcome this, I tried installing ARM EABI v7a System Image using sysimg_armv7a-14_r01.zip file.

Surprisingly, my Android SDK manage does not show option of ARM EABI v7a System Image to reinstall this package? Did I miss any step? 
[image]

Comment: same problem did you got any solution?

Comment: I have same problem on ubuntu 12.10. Earlier it was displaying, while downloading, system crashed and since then arm eabi v7a system image for non of the version 4.x and 4.x.x is displayed. For earlier version too it is not displayed but i m able to create emulators for that. But for 4.x and 4.x.x versions is not showing any downloading option nor it is allowing me to create simulator as system images are not found.

Answer (score 4):

use this link for manual download 
works perfect

http://androidhat.blogspot.in/2012/01/api-level-15-for-android-package-arm.html

for other api,s google

regards
Vishnu Manohar

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange. Userdata.img is a part of SDK files that are used for running emulator. Try to reinstall SDK. You shouldn't download images from other resources they are included in SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-15\armeabi-v7a\source.properties" is wrong **AndroidVersion.ApiLevel**.
Here is my "system-images\android-15\armeabi-v7a\source.properties".

```
---(from)---
    ### Android Tool: Source of this archive.
    #Thu Feb 23 09:48:52 JST 2012
    Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Platform 4.0.3
    Archive.Os=ANY
    AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=15
    Pkg.Revision=1
    SystemImage.Abi=armeabi-v7a
    Archive.Arch=ANY
    Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
---(end)---
```

Here is my "system-images\android-14\armeabi-v7a\source.properties"..

```
---(from)---
    ### Android Tool: Source of this archive.
    #Fri Feb 24 12:00:09 JST 2012
    Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Platform 4.0
    Archive.Os=ANY
    AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=14
    Pkg.Revision=2
    SystemImage.Abi=armeabi-v7a
    Archive.Arch=ANY
    Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
---(end)---
```

I recommend you to delete "c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-15\armeabi-v7a" folder and "c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-14\armeabi-v7a" folder.
Then Reinstalling become available, I think.
Please allow, if expression of my English is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the android sdk update system doesn't properly install this particular package. It keeps trying to install it.

Here´s the output on my Mac:

```
[...]
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  Installing ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
    Installed ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 199%)
  Done. 1 package installed.
Jeromes-MacBook-Pro:android-sdk-macosx lacostej$ tools/android update sdk --no-ui
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
[...]
  Fetching URL: http://developer.sonyericsson.com/edk/android/repository.xml
  Validate XML: http://developer.sonyericsson.com/edk/android/repository.xml
  Parse XML:    http://developer.sonyericsson.com/edk/android/repository.xml
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
```

Answer (score 0):

just install those in SDK manager in android studio and you will get solution

> -> Android suport Library
>
> -> Android SDK tools
>
> -> Android support repository

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the appropriate repository (highlighted in the image) add-on site registered on your SDK manager ,, in your SDK manager --> tools --> manage add-on sites, if the site is not there add it in the second tab (user defined sites).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7ldp.jpg)