# arm eabi v7a system image not found android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I've to develop a simple Android app using the Cordova API(PhoneGap) and it requires Android 4.0.3 or higher versions (API Level 15 or above) to build the app on the emulator correctly.

But, when I give a build for the coded app, I happen to see that I get this below error message,

```
[2012-07-02 13:10:29 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.
```

On googling this problem, I came to know that I need to install the `arm-eabi v7a system image` onto my machine for this to run smoothly.

But the issue is that, unlike API 14, this is not appearing for API 15!

Below image shows the same:
[image: arm-eabi-v7a-system-image]

Now, can anyone explain me how to fix this up, please? This is very peculiar to look at and re-installing the Manager/SDK/API Levels again and again was of no use.

Reference: [Android SDK Manager is not showing ARM EABI v7a System Image option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739090/android-sdk-manager-is-not-showing-arm-eabi-v7a-system-image-option)

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally this should not be the case.

For e.g. one does see the ARM EABI v7a System Image (API level 15) in the SDK Manager window.

You could try a few things:

- Reinstall the SDK.
- Alternatively, delete the ANDROID_SDK_INSTALL_FOLDER\system-images\android-15 folder and then install the SDK again and try.

Comment: The first method of yours, worked now. Wondering why it didn't before! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is:

From the Android SDK Manager, I have installed the following options:

- Platform SDK
- ARM EABI V7A System Image

For the API to work you need to do the following steps:

1. close eclipse
2. Go to  folder: `..\sdk\system-images`
3. Open the folder for the system image you use. I can inside a folder called *"default"* and in *"armeabi-v7a"* only have to cut and move *"armeabi-v7a"* where the *"default"* and then *"delete"* default.
4. open eclipse

Comment: Can you please try to rephrase point number #3. I am not able to understand it and therefore could not edit it in properly (basically left that part as it was). Thanks.